# How to make nice column in this thread

Tags: python

I wrote a script in python and at the end I get result like this:

```
urls = open(filename)
for line in urls:
    url = line.rstrip()
    data = Func(url)
    if data:
        line, a_param, b_param, c_param = data
        print '%s %d %d %d' % (line, a_param, b_param, c_param)
```

So I want to make a nice column for output... Could you possibly help me?

What I tried is:

```
out = '%s %d %d %d' % (line, a_param, b_param, c_param)
        col_width = max(len(word) for row in out for word in row) + 2 
        for row in out:
            print "%s %d %d %d".join(word.ljust(col_width) for word in row)
```

But no result... I mean the output sth lije this:

```
t
e
s
t

1  
9  
8  
4  
7  
9  
0  
0  

2  
0  
0  
7  
7  
5  
9  
0  

-  
1
```

I also changed code like so:

```
for row in out:
            print('{0:s} {1:d} {2:d} {3:d}'.format(str(row), int(row), int(row), int(row)))
```

and the following error has occured:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'l'
```

Answer (score 1):

if those are integers with different number of digits, you can just tell `print` to use a column of fixed size, e.g. like this:

```
>>> for i in [-1, 40, 999, 2]:
...   print "[% 5d]" % i
... 
[   -1]
[   40]
[  999]
[    2]
```

so, if you know the maximal length of a column you can just specify it explicitly in the format string:

```
print '% 10s % 5d % 4d % 3d' % ...
```

here's an overview of different formatting options: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

this converts the string of all params to a list:

```
words = out.split()
```

then compute the longest "word"

```
col_width = max(len(word) for word in words) + 2
```

and set in cols

```
for word in words:
    print("".join(word.ljust(col_width)), end="")
```

Does this help?

Comment: A syntax Error over `end="")`

Comment: when I remove `end=""` It shows result but in 1 column

Comment: so you're on Python 2.7?

replace the last line with

`print "".join(word.ljust(col_width)),`

Comment: It is showing the result in one column and with this pattern: `('content',)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are iterating the wrong way. You're assigning out to a str, and then iterating over the str. You want to iterate over the items you find in data.

```
out = []
maxlen = 0
urls = open(filename)
for line in urls:
    url = line.rstrip()
    data = Func(url)
    if data:
        # calculate the longest word.
        tmplen = max(len(word) for word in data)
        # store the result
        maxlen = tmplen if templen > maxlen else maxlen
        # keep the data around for iterating later
        out.append(data)

# loop through all of the data stored earlier 
for line in out:
    # lambda creates a function.
    # str(x) converts to a str, ljust makes it the right length
    # map applies the function to all of the items in the list.
    print ''.join(map(lamda x: str(x).ljust(maxlen), line))
```

Comment: I don't know why I have this error:`  print ''.join(map(lamda x: str(x).ljust(maxlen), line))
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: This works well: `print ''.join(map(lambda x: str(x).rjust(5)+'|',[1,2,3, 'cat', 'banan','','duck']))`

Comment: Could there be a copy and paste problem?